# Bug in variant 'Outlined' Vuetify 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX68i.png)

I have a bug in my application in the "Outlined" variant in the  tag of vuetify 3, can someone who has experienced this error please help me?

```
<v-text-field
            class="rounded-full border-slate-300 sm:order-last w-full sm:min-w-[270px]"
            variant="outlined"
            v-model="search"
            label="Pesquisar por aluno"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
            hide-details="auto"
            color="#0284FE"
          >
</v-text-field>
```

I've tried removing the 'details' but to no avail

Comment: This should work, and [it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wotQx.png) when I try it out. Consider adding a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com) to your question where the problem can be inspected.

Comment: Exact Vuetify version and platform/browser information could be relevant as well.